# How do I get across Episode 4's maze?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

I'm playing Episode 4, which was released yesterday. I'm at the part at far lands where we are finding Ivor's lair.

I'm at the top of the maze right now and I can't seem to find a way to get across it. How do I cross the maze?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured that out. In fact it wasn't that hard. So you need to get to the lava flow, there you will face with a witch, finish her and go forth to the end and then turn left and that's it. Hope it helpful. =)

Comment: I remember that first Jesse talks to Olivia and then a spider attacks Jesse. Then later a witch attacks. I didn't try myself I just found out on the internet. Sorry that spoiled me.